# OCaml: error in list function

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

Hello I am working on list of function in Ocaml I am getting this error why is that?

```
Error: Syntax error
# let headOf lst=
  match lst with
  |??[ ] -> failwith "harun"
Warning 3: deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers
```

Comment: The code you pasted here  has two question marks in it `??`. Most likely this is because there is some rather strange character at that spot in your actual code. This is very likely the source of both your syntax error and the warning about strange characters.

Comment: No I did not write question marks in it, When I past the another line it gives this error.

Comment: The question marks are almost certainly a symptom of your problem. You don't give enough information to help more than this, sorry. My suggestion is to start with a new source file, and make sure you're using a straightforward character encoding for your source file. It should work to use UTF-8 as long as non-ASCII characters occur only in string constants and comments. You could even try just starting with a pure ASCII file.

Comment: I upload photo here, can you look at the answers part?

Answer (score 1):

If your input encoding is ISO-LATIN-1, then what you're doing is typing *non-breaking spaces* sometimes. These are non-ASCII characters that look like spaces, with a character code of 160. You should remove them all and replace with ordinary spaces (character code 32).

If you're using an input system that sometimes inputs non-breaking spaces without your specifically asking for them, you should use a different input system for working with OCaml :-)

**Update**

In fact, *my* input system inputs a non-breaking space if I type Option-Space (iTerm2 on macOS 10.12.4). It looks like this:

```
# let f x��= 14;;
Warning 3: deprecated: ISO-Latin1 characters in identifiers
Error: Illegal character (\160)
```

The solution in my case is never to type Option-Space. Just type space (no option key).